# When we reinstal a debian package, is that messy?

Tags: package-management, lubuntu, vnc, deb, debian

I just did a fresh install of Lubuntu 20.10 and made a mistake trying to get VNC Server to start, which is a deb package installed with gdebi. I thought perhaps reinstalling the VNC deb package might help. So I reinstalled VNC to no avail (The problem was that I was typing the wrong set of commands into the terminal).

I am wondering if reinstalling a debian package simply overwrites existing files or if new files with new names are created?

I ran BleachBit but am curious. It's a new install and I want to keep it clean and light.

Answer (score 1):

When a package is reinstalled, the files are overwritten. The installation is not "messy".

All files are installed at standard locations required for the package.

An easy way to see which files will be installed (overwritten) is by going to [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/):

1. Open https://packages.ubuntu.com/ in your web browser
2. Enter your package information, and click Search
3. On the next page select your package. ([Example Package Search Results for VNC](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=VNC&searchon=names&suite=groovy&section=all)).
4. You will see a page listing information about your package. It will also list other packages that your package is dependent on. ([Example package information for directvnc](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/directvnc))
5. At the bottom, you will see links "[list of files]"
6. Once you click one of these links for your architecture, you will see a list of files and directories that will be updated if you install the package. ([Example file list for the directvnc package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/directvnc/filelist)). Note that this listing does not show files for other packages that your selected package depends on. To see those, you can click the Back button ins your browser and select the dependent packages.

Answer (score 1):

".deb" files are managed by the APT package management system, so installation is registered in the system, automatically controlled and reversible.

Files installed from a `.deb` will be installed in specific places. Thus, on a reinstall, existing files are overwritten. Installed files are automatically removed again when uninstalling the package using Software Center, or synaptic package manager or `apt remove <package>` on the terminal.

An exception here are [system wide configuration](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html) files that may be installed by a `.deb`package. Configuration files are not automatically overwritten if they already exist, and are not automatically removed when the package is removed. In order to remove installed configuration files, you must explicitly tell so by adding the `--purge` option, e.g. `apt remove --purge <package>`.